# Gramatically correct function declaration

Tags: jquery

I have some production code that I am running jsHint and jsLint through, and the report that it comes back makes me very unease. I have limited jQuery experience and would like to ask you gurus out there the correct way of function declaration.

**My Code:**

```
init : function() {
    // some code
},
```

jsHint reports back that everything is fine.

jsLint reports back this..

```
Expected exactly one space between 'function' and '('.
    init : function() {
```

This goes same for all my other functions with the same error. This may sound tedious, but is there suppose to be a space between `function` and `(` to be correct? Code runs fine without that expected space and without that expected space.

Comment: Ah sorry for the redundant question. I didn't catch this in another post. Guess the way I typed the question didn't show any results.

Comment: You need to disable the ***messy white space*** flag.

Comment: That helped in sorting through errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a style correction by jsLint, to make the code more readable and errors easier to spot. As you say, the code will work fine without the space. By requiring the space, jsLint just makes the code easier to read and maintain.

On a little project or a single function, this kind of thing is not very important. On a big project, like a library, it becomes very important and is a huge help.

Comment: Thanks! Like the other post says, that it was about how readable it was. Then I won't worry about it, because it bugs me that there needs to be a space.